# How to create auto-increment field in select query in Access 2010?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, auto-increment

I have a list of inventory entries. Each entry has a date, item name, and volumes. What I'm doing now is selecting the top 10 items based on the most recent-date volumes, and then tracking the volumes of these items over the past 5 days in my table. The one piece I'm missing is that I would like to order the resulting table based on the most recent-date volume order of the items, i.e.

```
Date  Item   Volumes
1/20  Dog    5
1/20  Bird   4
1/20  Cat    2
1/19  Dog    3
1/19  Bird   6
1/19  Cat    10
1/18  Dog    0
1/18  Bird   2
1/18  Cat    0
```

Below is a scrubbed version of the sql code I'm running. As of now the second sort I'm doing after sorting on the date is just sorting alphabetically on the item name.

```
SELECT 
 TOP_VOLUMES.NAME, 
 DATA.VOLUMES, 
 DATA.TIMESTAMP
FROM DATA 
RIGHT JOIN 
 (SELECT TOP 10 NAME
  FROM DATA 
  WHERE TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM DATA) 
  ORDER BY VOLUMES DESC, NAME) AS TOP_VOLUMES 
ON TOP_VOLUMES.NAME = DATA.NAME
WHERE ((SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM DATA) - DATA.TIMESTAMP < 5)
ORDER BY DATA.TIMESTAMP DESC , DATA.NAME;
```

I would really like to avoid creating any temp tables for this. Is there any way to do it within the select statement within the join? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you are asking two questions.   One how to auto-increment a field, and the second is how to sort by the date.  Can you clarify with a single sentence what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I know how to sort by the date, I would just like to learn how to add a field in a select query that auto-increments. In my example query, in the last line, I would like it to read `ORDER BY DATA.TIMESTAMP DESC, TOP_VOLUMES.RANK` where `RANK` is some auto-incrementing field I've added to the inner select statement.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a link which may contain the answer you are looking for-
[Access SQL how to make an increment in SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294382/access-sql-how-to-make-an-increment-in-select-query)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for the response; I already looked through this and couldn't make the one solution work for me since I don't have a unique ID for each field, and I would prefer not to write VBA code. I will take another look through this, though - thanks!